# How to access dictionary keys within a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have some code below that I get if I do print dict.json():

```
dict.json() =  {'random_string': { 'a': 'random_value_int',
                     'b': 'random_value__strings,
                     'c': 000,
                     'd': 321,
                     'e': ['ABC', 'CBA']},
     'random_string_2': { 'a': 'random_value_int_2',
                     'b': 'random_value__strings_2,
                     'c': 000,
                     'd': 321,
                     'e': ['ABC', 'CBA']}}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to pull 'random_string', 'a', 'random_value_strings', and ['ABC', 'CBA']. 
Also, I'm trying to figure out how to store each of the keys/values in a list to use for later. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not quite sure what your intended output is. You can get the keys from your dict by doing `dict.json().keys()`, and store that in a list or what-have-you. As for pulling, that follows standard array access syntax of `array[vector]`

Comment: Is your example a string output from dict.json? Please provide a clearer example.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary you posted is a `nested dictionary` which is a dictionary or dictionaries inside a dictionary.

```py
my_dict = {'random_string': { 'a': 'random_value_int',
                     'b': 'random_value__strings',
                     'c': 000,
                     'd': 321,
                     'e': ['ABC', 'CBA']},
     'random_string_2': { 'a': 'random_value_int_2',
                     'b': 'random_value__strings_2',
                     'c': 000,
                     'd': 321,
                     'e': ['ABC', 'CBA']}}
```

I have used the `random_string` nested dictionary for the examples below.

**First let us access the keys:**

You just need to go deep into the dictionary until you reach the key you want to access.

```py
>>> my_dict['random_string']
{'a': 'random_value_int', 'b': 'random_value__strings', 'c': 0, 'd': 321, 'e': ['ABC', 'CBA']}
>>> my_dict['random_string']['a']
'random_value_int'
>>> my_dict['random_string']['e']
['ABC', 'CBA']
```

**Storing key:value pairs in a list**

There is a built-in dictionary method called `items()` that returns a list of `(key,value)` pairs as a `tuple` of type `dict_items`.

You can convert it to `list` type using the `list()` function.

```py
>>> list_key_val = list(my_dict['random_string'].items())
>>> list_key_val
[('a', 'random_value_int'), ('b', 'random_value__strings'), ('c', 0), ('d', 321), ('e', ['ABC', 'CBA'])]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I can see how I can access it the way you provided, but my problem comes when I try to iterate through the random_string because each key of the nested dicts are actually random, and I have about 1,000 of the random strings.